# php including file

Tags: php, include, directory, require

I have to include in a php script some files that are located on a 2nd level subdirectory.
The problem is that in my xampp it fails to include these files.
In netbeans if i click on the path it open files.

```
require_once("../../config/bootstrap.php");
require_once("../../config/config.php");
```

What may be the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you accessing this file directly or are you including it, too?

Comment: Then my answer should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../config/bootstrap.php");
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../config/config.php");
```

Or in PHP 5.3+

```
require_once(__DIR__ . "/../../config/bootstrap.php");
require_once(__DIR__ . "/../../config/config.php");
```

Answer (score 2):

you would not normally want to have ..'s in your include files. you may want to bootstrap your webapp with an environment value (in apache, you can use SetEnv for this) and then from you webapp you can 

`$dir = getenv('APPLICATION_PATH');
require_once($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'bootstrap.php);`

Also, you can set APPLICATION_CONFIG_PATH instead, saving up one DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.

to sum up.. I'd try to avoid ..'s and also hardcoding the '/' (using an environment variable to bootstrap the app and the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR respectively)

EDIT: forgot to mention: if you're using PHP 5.3, you may get away with using the ../.. with **DIR** . '../..'.

**DIR** will resolve to the directory containing the actual running script

Comment: Do you have some tutorial for bootstrap coding in php? I would learn it.

Comment: to bootstrap a php webapp in apache, you can use http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_env.html#setenv. this will set an environment value, very useful to get some "properties" to your code. in a console app, you can also use environment values, setting them before executing your script. from php, you can set and get environment values by using getenv() and putenv()

Comment: EDIT: forgot to mention: if you're using PHP 5.3, you may get away with using the ../.. with DIR . '../..'.
DIR will resolve to the directory containing the actual running script

I have not understood what you mean sorry..

Comment: i meant the constant <underscore><underscore>DIR<underscore><underscore> (sorry to write it like this, just because of the markdown here in stackoverflow.. you can find these constants here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php). in this case, __DIR__ resolves automagically to dirname(__FILE__)

Answer (score 0):

this should work perfectly with this directory tree, assuming you'Re accessing public/public/index.php

- root

  - public

    - public

      - index.php
  - config

    - config.php
    - bootstrap.php

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

In my personal experience, i've found the most consistency from always creating relative references based on the include_path.